# $R[X]/(f)$ separable $\iff \Delta(f) \in R^*$?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$. Let $f \in R[X]$ be monic. I have to prove the following:
$$
\text{The discriminant of } f \text{ is invertible}
\quad \quad
\iff
\quad \quad
R[X] / (f) \text{ a is separable algebra over R}
$$
Could you please help me to do so?

---

**The definitions I work with**

For me the *discriminant* of a polynomial $f$ is understood to be
$$
\Delta(f) \ := \ \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (\alpha_i - \alpha_j)^2.  
$$
We call an algebra $B$ *separable* iff the following map is bijective:
$$
\Phi \ : \ B \rightarrow Hom(B,R) \ : \ 
x \ \longmapsto \ \left(y \mapsto Tr(xy)\right)
$$
where the trace of an element $b \in B$ is defined as the trace of the map
$ x \mapsto bx$.

---

**My own thoughts**

We tried to use another fact about separability of algebras
from [this source](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf):

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, B an $R$-algebra with basis 
>   $\{w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n \}$, then 
>   $$
> \det(Tr(w_iw_j):1 \leq i,j \leq n ) \text{ is invertible}
> \quad \quad
> \iff
> \quad \quad
> \text{ B is a separable algebra over $R$}
> $$
>   Where $Tr(a)$ is a notation for the trace of the map
>   $$
> B \ \longrightarrow \ B \ : \ x \ \longmapsto \ ax
> $$

Thus it would make sense to try to prove that $\Delta(f) = (Tr(w_iw_j):i,j)$, but we only managed to prove this for polynomials of degree two. In the general case both sides are very hard to calculate

---

**Some computational effort**

Lets write $f(X) = a_0 + a_1X + \dots + a_nX^n$. 
In our case $\{1,X,X^2,\dots, X^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $A[X]/(f)$.
The determinant we have to calculate looks like if $n=3$:
$$
 \left| \begin{array}
        Tr(1) & Tr(X) & Tr(X^2) \\
        Tr(X) & Tr(X^2) & Tr(X^3) \\
        Tr(X^2) & Tr(X^3) & Tr(X^4) \\
        \end{array}
\right|
$$
and is similar for other $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Below I "sketched" what the matrix of a map $f(X) \mapsto X^j f(X)$ looks like.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
      0& 0& \dots &0 \\
      \vdots& \vdots & & \vdots \\
      0& 0& \dots &0 \\
      \hline
      1 &0 &\dots &0 & \\
      0 &1 &\dots &0 && \\
      \vdots & \vdots &  \\
      0 &0 & \dots &1  &&&&  \\
    \end{array}
\right] $$
The empty parts are hard to spell out. At least we can see this way that for taking the trace we only need te consider the elements on the right.
This is still hard, though. The discriminant isn't easy to calculate either.

---

Could you please help me to solve this? Feel free to use any method you like.

Comment: what does delta mean here? Does it mean the eva;uation function

Comment: $\Delta$ should be the discriminant. At least it seems the statement is true in that case. Here is an Idea, which seems a bit too complicated to me: by general theory of commutative separable extensions (key word unramified), we can reduce to the case where $R$ is a field and $f$ is irreducible. Then the statement becomes: $R[x]/f$ is separable over $R$ if and only if $f$ is a separable polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick way to prove it, but quick only because a lot of things are considered well known.

A finite type extension $S/R$ of commutative rings is separable if and only if $\Omega_{S/R}$, the module of Kähler differentials, is trivial.
Let's show that this is equivalent to $f$ having an invertible discriminant.

For sake of clarity: I usually define $\Delta(f)$ as the resultant of $f$ and $f'$.
In the special case where $f$ is monic, it turns out that $\Delta(f):=\operatorname{res}(f,f')$ equals the norm of $f'\in R[x]/(f)$ over $R$, i.e., the determinant of the $R$-linear endomorphism of $R[x]/(f)$ given by multiplication with $f'$.
In particular, $f'$ is a unit in $R[x]/(f)$ if and only if $\Delta(f)$ is a unit in $R$.

Associated with the surjection $S:= R[x]\to S' := R[x]/(f)$ with kernel $(f)$ we get an exact sequence
$$(f)/(f)^2\to \Omega_{S/R}\otimes_{S} S'\to\Omega_{S'/R}\to 0.$$
We aim to show that $\Omega_{S'/R} = 0$.
As $S = R[x]$, it is well known that $\Omega_{S/R} = S\mathrm{d}x$, so $\Omega_{S/R}\otimes_{S} S' = S'\mathrm{d}x$.
For $\Omega_{S'/R} = 0$ to hold, the leftmost map, on $h+(f^2)\in (f)/(f^2)$ defined as $\mathrm{d}h\otimes 1$, has to be surjective.
Plugging in a general element $h = fg$ shows that this holds if and only if $f' $ is a unit in $S'$.
By the previous remarks this shows that $S'/R$ is separable if and only if $\Delta(f)$ is a unit in $R$, as claimed.

**Addendum:** A rather elementary proof, closer to the OPs definitions. I found it in the (german) book on algebra by Bosch.

First, allow me another definition of the discriminant as indicated by the OP.
It differs from $\operatorname{res}(f,f')$ in a sign.
To clearly distinguish them, I'll denote the new one by $\delta_f$ instead.
Let me use the following without proof (key word: fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials).
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a kind of universal discriminant for polynomials of degree $n$ as follows.

Let $s_0,s_1,\dots,s_n\in \mathbb{Z}[t_1,\dots,t_n]$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials; more precisely, the unique polynomials such that $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-t_i)=\sum_{i=0}^n s_ix^{n-i}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,t_1,\dots, t_n]$.
They are algebraically independent and generate the sub-ring of symmetric polynomials, i.e., the map
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n]\to\mathbb{Z}[t_1,\dots,t_n], \sigma_i\mapsto s_i,$$
is injective and its image consists precisely of the symmetric polynomials.
In particular, there is a unique polynomial $\Delta^n\in\mathbb{Z}[\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n]$ which is mapped to the symmetric polynomial $\prod_{i<j}(t_i-t_j)^2$.

Now, if $R$ is any commutative ring and $f = x^n + f_{1}x^{n-1}+\dots+f_{n-1}x+f_n\in R[x]$, consider the unique ring map $\chi_f\colon \mathbb{Z}[\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n]\to R$ defined by $\sigma_i\mapsto f_i$.
Then the *discriminant of $f$* is defined as $\delta_f := \chi_f(\Delta^n)$; in other words, $\delta_f = \Delta^n(f_1,f_2,\dots  f_n)$.

Note that, whenever $R\subset R'$ is such that $f = \prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i)$ with $\alpha_i\in R'$, since $f_i = \sigma_i(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$, we get
$\delta_f = \Delta^n(f_1,\ldots,f_n) = \prod_{i<j}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2,$
as expected.

This construction shows that if $\varphi\colon R\to R'$ is any ring homomorphism and $f\in R[x]$ is any monic polynomial, then $\delta_{\varphi(f)} = \varphi(\delta_f)$. This will be important later.

Now to the actual problem.
Recall that if $f\in R[x]$ is monic of degree $n$, then $S:=R[x]/(f)$ is free as $R$-module of rank $n$, with basis $1,x,\dots x^{n-1}$.

This allows the definition of $S/R$ to be separable via non-degeneracy of the trace form, as the OP does.
If we identify $\mathrm{Hom}(S,R)$, as $R$-module, with $R^n$ via the basis dual to the one chosen above, we see that $S/R$ is separable if and only if the matrix
$(\mathop{Tr}(x^{i+j}))_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}$
is invertible.
Since this matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible, we get the equivalence cited by the OP.

We will reduce the problem to a special case, so this determinant needs a name; given a monic $f\in R[x]$ of degree $n$, let
$$\mathrm{disc}_{R,f} := \det(\mathop{Tr}(x^{i+j}))_{0\leq i,j\leq n-1}\in R.$$
We aim to show that $\mathrm{disc}_{R,f} = \delta_f$.

Observe that if $\varphi\colon R\to R'$ is a ring homomorphism and $f\in R[x]$ is a monic polynomial, then so is $\varphi(f)\in R'[x]$ and $\mathrm{disc}_{R',\varphi(f)} = \varphi(\mathrm{disc}_{R,f})$, since the trace behaves accordingly.
In particular,

- if $\delta_f = \mathrm{disc}_{R,f}$, then $\delta_{\varphi(f)} = \mathrm{disc}_{R',\varphi(f)}$ and
- $\delta_f = \mathrm{disc}_{R,f}$ if and only if $\delta_{\varphi(f)} = \mathrm{disc}_{R',\varphi(f)}$ in case $\varphi$ is injective.

As a first reduction step, let $f = x^n + f_{1}x^{n-1}+\dots+f_{n-1}x+f_n\in R[x]$ and consider the map $A:=\mathbb{Z}[\sigma_1,\dots, \sigma_n]\to R$, $\sigma_i\mapsto f_i$.
Then we see that to prove the claim for $f$, it suffices to prove it for $\sum_{i=0}^n\sigma_ix^{n-i}\in A[x]$.
In the next step, we will use the inclusion $A\subset \mathrm{Frac}(A) = \mathbb{Q}(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n) =: k$.
Since it is an inclusion, it suffices to prove the claim for $f:= \sum_{i=0}^n\sigma_ix^{n-i}\in k[X]$.
$f$ is irreducible.

Therefore, we have reduced the problem to the case of an algebraic field extension $L:=k[x]/(f)$ over $k$, where $f$ is irreducible of degree $n$.
Choose an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$ and let $f = \prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i)$ with $\alpha_i\in \overline{k}$.

Here comes the final trick: in this special situation, we have $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/k}(x^j) = \sum_{\ell=1}^n\alpha^j_\ell$.
The case $j=1$ is easy to see as $-\mathrm{Tr}(x)$ is the degree $(n-1)$-coefficient of the minimal polynomial of $x$, which is $f$.
The case $j>1$ follows from the former case by basic eigenvalue-theory.

Finally, observe that
$$\mathrm{disc}_{k,f} = \det\left(\sum_{\ell=1}^n\alpha_\ell^{i+j}\right)_{i,j} = \det(V^tV) = \det(V)^2 = \left(\prod_{i<j}^n(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)\right)^2=\delta_f,$$
where $V = (\alpha_\ell^j)_{\ell,j}$ (here $1\leq \ell\leq n$, but $0\leq j\leq n-1$) is the Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: There has to be a more elementary road through this, maybe really identifying the discriminant of $f$ and the discriminant of the trace pairing. I'd really like to see such a proof!

Comment: I awarded the bounty to you because there are no other answers. I didn't know what Kähler differentials and resultants are. I read the dedicated Wikipedia pages and that contains a lot of information about it but I can't understand your answer yet. Maybe one day I will ;-)

Comment: Dear @KoenraadvanDuin, in that case I will think about another proof. It would be easier to produce something helpful if I knew the precise definition of separable and of the discriminant you are working with. Perhaps you can include the definitions in the question.

Comment: Dear @KoenraadvanDuin, there it is.

Comment: I understand the most of your answer. Neverhteless I have some things to ask you. First of all about $\phi : R \rightarrow R'$. I guess you extend such a map to $\phi' : R[X] \rightarrow R'[X] \ : \ \sum a_j X^j \mapsto \sum \phi(a_j) X^j $. You state that $\phi(disc_{R,f}) = disc_{R', \phi(f)}$. I don't understand exactly what you are doing with the ring $A$ either but maybe that will come later.

Comment: You're right with $\varphi'\colon R[x]\to R'[x]$. The reason for $\varphi(\mathrm{disc}_{R,f}) = \mathrm{disc}_{R',\varphi'(f)}$ is the following. The determinant is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, so it commutes with $\varphi$ in the appropriate sense; therefore, it suffices to note that $\varphi(\mathrm{Tr}_{R[x]/(f)]}(x^{i})) = \mathrm{Tr}_{R'[x]/(\varphi'(f))}(\varphi(x^{i})) = \mathrm{Tr}_{R'[x]/(\varphi'(f))}(x^{i})$.

Comment: Dear @Ben, I came across your answer when asking me the same thing. I've seen that for two fields, the field extension is separable if and only if the relative Kaehler differential is trivial but I have never seen it for arbitrary rings. I wasn't able to find a proof for it online. Would you mind giving a reference for the more general result?

Comment: Dear @M.Wang, sure — Knus, Ojanguren, *Théorie de la descente et algèbres d’Azumaya*, Chapter III is my standard reference for this stuff, in particular Th. 1.4. If you feel that this is overkill, you should ask a separate question. (And don’t forget to explicitly state the definitions you are working with; loc. cit. shows that there are quite a few candidates...)